# Printing Successor and Predecessor in a BST

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, traversal, binary-search-tree

My problem is as follows:

I have a binary search tree with keys: `a1<a2<...<an`, the problem is to print all the (a_i, a_i+1) pairs in the tree (where i={1,2,3,...}) using a recursive algorithm in O(n) time without any global variable and using O(1) extra space. An example:
Let the keys be: 1,2, ..., 5
Pairs that will be printed: (1,2) (2,3) (3, 4) (4, 5)

So you can't do inorder traversal in the tree and find the successor/predecessor for each node. Because that would take O(nh) time and if the tree is balanced, it will be O(nlgn) for the whole tree.

Comment: An in-order traversal is not O(nlgn)...

Comment: yes inorder traversal is O(n) but on average case successor function is O(h) and in the worst case O(n) so if you call successor or predecessor for each node on average  it will be O(nlgn) but in the worst case it is quadratic.

Comment: That's not true.  In a complete traversal, each node is "visited" a maximum of 3 times (once on descent, and twice on return).

Comment: In fact, the total number of node "visits" is exactly 2n; each node is entered once (from above), and exited once (to above).

Comment: so in big oh notation it will be O(2n)=O(n) or am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything ;)

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: hey staafl, sorry I had some other staffs to do and couldn't check this thread. As for your question I couldn't make your algorithm work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you are right that finding an in-order successor or predecessor might take O(h) time, it turns out that if you start at the smallest value in a BST and repeatedly find its successor, the total amount of work done ends up coming out to O(n) regardless of the shape of the tree.

On intuition for this is to think about how many times you traverse each edge in the tree when iteratively doing successor lookups.  Specifically, you will visit every edge in the tree exactly twice: once when you descend into the subtree, and once when you walk up out of it having visited every node in that subtree.  Since an n-node tree has O(n) edges, this takes time O(n) to complete.

If you're skeptical about this, try writing a simple program to verify it.  I remember not believing this result when I first heard it until I wrote a program to confirm it. :-)

In pseudocode, the logic would look like this:

1. Find the lowest value in the tree by starting at the root and repeatedly following the left child pointer until no such pointer exists.
2. Until all nodes are visited, remember the current node and find its successor as follows:

   1. If the current node has a right child:

      1. Go right.
      2. Go left until there are no left children left.
      3. Output the node you started at, then this node.
         2: Otherwise:
      4. Walk up to the parent node until you find that the node you started at was a left child of its parent.
      5. If you hit the root and never found that you traversed from a left child upward, you are done.
      6. Otherwise, output the node you remembers, then the current node.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi @templatetypedef I believed that this algo is O(n) when I saw its proof :) (http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/binarySearchTree.htm). Yep this algorithm works, but its recursive implementation is kind of complicated. I've  an intuition that it has a less complex recursive implementation with ordinary inorder traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Oli is right that inorder traversal is O(n), but you are right that using the general successor/predecessor routines will increase the algorithmic complexity. So:

A simple solution would be to walk the tree using in-order traversal, keeping track of the last time you're taken a right-pointing edge (say, using a variable called **last_right_ancestor_seen** to point to its parent node) and the last leaf node you've seen (say, in **last_leaf_seen** (actually, any node without a right child). Every time you process a leaf node, its predecessor is **last_right_ancestor**, and every time you hit a non-leaf node, its predecessor is **last_leaf_seen**, and you just print the two. O(n) time, O(1) space.

Hope it's clear enough, I can draw you a diagram if not.

Edit: This is untested but probably correct:

```
walk(node* current, node* last_right_ancestor_seen, node* last_leaf_seen) {

    if(current->left != null) {
        walk(current->left, last_right_ancestor_seen, last_leaf_seen);
    }

    if(current->is_leaf()) {
            if(last_right_ancestor_seen != null)
                print(last_right_ancestor_seen->value, current->value);
    }
    else {
        print(last_leaf_seen->value, current->value);
    }

    if(current->right != null) {
        *last_right_ancestor_seen = *current;
        walk(current->right, last_right_ancestor_seen, last_leaf_seen);
    }
    else {
        *last_leaf_seen = *current;
    }

}
```

Comment: note that a recursive algorithm implicitly uses storage for the call stack, in this case O(h), but the problem statement probably chooses to ignore that

Comment: but how do you store these variables without using global variables for last_right_ancesstor_seen and last_leaf_seen? I might be misinterpreting. but can you give a pseudocode? Stack-space isn't important.

Comment: You can pass them as parameters to each recursive call :-)

Comment: sorry that was a stupid question :). I'm going to try your algorithm thanks.

Comment: this seems like not working in the line with `if(current->is_leaf()) { print(last_right_ancestor_seen->value, current->value);}` I got last_right_ancestor_seen->value null that makes sense because you set the last_right_ancestor_seen only when you make right turn, but if the tree is left-leaning it may never have a right ancestor.

Comment: ... and the leaf has no predecessor. Good catch, updated the pseudo-code.

Comment: why are you trying to find the predecessor of each node instead of successor. Finding the successor of each node and printing with the predecessor seems more intuitive for me.

Comment: I'm not trying to find the predecessor of each node individually, just walking the tree and printing out each time a predecessor/successor pair is established, using the properties of BSTs. It's not exactly intuitive, but clever algorithms seldom are :-)