# Java: How to find k values in the BST that are closest to the target?

Tags: java, algorithm, traversal, inorder

I'm researching on how to find k values in the BST that are closest to the target, and came across the following implementation with the rules:

> Given a non-empty binary search tree and a target value, find k values in the BST that are closest to the target.
>
> Note:
>
> Given target value is a floating point.
> You may assume k is always valid, that is: k ≤ total nodes.
> You are guaranteed to have only one unique set of k values in the BST that are closest to the target. Assume that the BST is balanced.

And the idea of the implementation is:

> Compare the predecessors and successors of the closest node to the target, we can use two stacks to track the predecessors and successors, then like what we do in merge sort, we compare and pick the closest one to the target and put it to the result list. As we know, inorder traversal gives us sorted predecessors, whereas reverse-inorder traversal gives us sorted successors.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

class TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode left, right;
    
    TreeNode(int x) { 
        val = x; 
    }
}


public class ClosestBSTValueII {
    List<Integer> closestKValues(TreeNode root, double target, int k) {
          List<Integer> res = new ArrayList<>();

          Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<>(); // predecessors
          
          Stack<Integer> s2 = new Stack<>(); // successors

          inorder(root, target, false, s1);
          inorder(root, target, true, s2);
          
          while (k-- > 0) {
            if (s1.isEmpty()) {
              res.add(s2.pop());
            } else if (s2.isEmpty()) {
              res.add(s1.pop());
            } else if (Math.abs(s1.peek() - target) < Math.abs(s2.peek() - target)) {
              res.add(s1.pop());
            } else {
              res.add(s2.pop());
            }
          }
          
          return res;
        }

    // inorder traversal
    void inorder(TreeNode root, double target, boolean reverse, Stack<Integer> stack) {
      
      if (root == null) {
          return;
      }

      inorder(reverse ? root.right : root.left, target, reverse, stack);
      // early terminate, no need to traverse the whole tree
      if ((reverse && root.val <= target) || (!reverse && root.val > target)) {
          return;
      }
      // track the value of current node
      stack.push(root.val);
      inorder(reverse ? root.left : root.right, target, reverse, stack);
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ClosestBSTValueII cv = new ClosestBSTValueII();
        
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(53);
        root.left = new TreeNode(30);
        root.left.left = new TreeNode(20);
        root.left.right = new TreeNode(42);
        root.right = new TreeNode(90);
        root.right.right = new TreeNode(100);
        
        System.out.println(cv.closestKValues(root, 40, 2));
    }
}
```

And my question is, what's the reason for having two stacks and how is in-order a good approach? What's the purpose of each? Wouldn't traversing it with one stack be enough?

And what's the point of having a `reverse` boolean, such as for `inorder(reverse ? ...);`? And in the case of `if ((reverse && root.val <= target) || (!reverse && root.val > target))`, why do you terminate early?

Thank you in advance and will accept answer/up vote.

Comment: If your code already be working, then this question might fit better on the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question, do you want to find the successor node? You can do that with a recursive approach.

Comment: @Baxtex I'm simply trying to understand the approach.

Comment: Hey, look at my answer! I tried to explain everything as clearly as possible, hope you will like it

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you need two stack is that you must traverse the tree in two directions, and you must compare the current value of each stack with the value you're searching (you may end up having k values greater than the searched value, or k/2 greater and k/2 lower).

I think you should use stacks of TreeNodes rather that stacks of Integer; you could avoid recursion.

UPDATE:

I see two phases in the algorithm:

1) locate the closest value in the tree, that would simultaneously build the initial stack.

2) make a copy of the stack, move back one element, this will give you the second stack; then iterate at most k times: see which of the two elements on top of each stack is the closest to the searched value, add it to the result list, and move the stack forward or backward.

UPDATE 2: A little code

```
public static List<Integer> closest(TreeNode root, int val, int k) {
    Stack<TreeNode> right = locate(root, val);
    Stack<TreeNode> left = new Stack<>();
    left.addAll(right);
    moveLeft(left);
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        if (left.isEmpty()) {
            if (right.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            result.add(right.peek().val);
            moveRight(right);
        } else if (right.isEmpty()) {
            result.add(left.peek().val);
            moveLeft(left);
        } else {
            int lval = left.peek().val;
            int rval = right.peek().val;
            if (Math.abs(val-lval) < Math.abs(val-rval)) {
                result.add(lval);
                moveLeft(left);
            } else {
                result.add(rval);
                moveRight(right);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private static Stack<TreeNode> locate(TreeNode p, int val) {
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
    while (p != null) {
        stack.push(p);
        if (val < p.val) {
            p = p.left;
        } else {
            p = p.right;
        }
    }
    return stack;
}

private static void moveLeft(Stack<TreeNode> stack) {
    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode p = stack.peek().left;
        if (p != null) {
            do {
                stack.push(p);
                p = p.right;
            } while (p != null);
        } else {
            do {
                p = stack.pop();
            } while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek().left == p);
        }
    }
}

private static void moveRight(Stack<TreeNode> stack) {
    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode p = stack.peek().right;
        if (p != null) {
            do {
                stack.push(p);
                p = p.left;
            } while (p != null);
        } else {
            do {
                p = stack.pop();
            } while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek().right == p);
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 3

> Wouldn't traversing it with one stack be enough?
>
> And what's the point of having a reverse boolean, such as for
>   inorder(reverse ? ...);? And in the case of if ((reverse && root.val
>   <= target) || (!reverse && root.val > target)), why do you terminate
>   early?

I don't know where you got the solution you gave in you're question from, but to summarize, it builds two lists of Integer, one in straight order, one in reverse order. It terminates "early" when the searched value is reached. This solution sound very inefficient since it requires the traversal of the whole tree. Mine, of course, is much better, and it conforms to the given rules.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of the algorithm you found is quite simple. They do just in-order traversal of a tree from the place, where `target` should be inserted. They use two stacks to store predecessors and successors. Lets take the tree for example:

```
     5
    / \
   3   9
  / \   \
 2   4   11
```

Let the target be `8`. When all `inorder` method calls are finished, stacks will be: `s1 = {2, 3, 4, 5}`, `s2 = {11, 9}`. As you see, `s1` contains all predecessors of `target` and `s2` all successors of it. Moreover, both stacks are sorted in a way, that `top` of each stack is closer to `target`, than all other values in stack. As a result, we can easily find `k`closest values, just by always comparing tops of the stacks, and popping the closest value until we have `k` values. The running time of their algorithm is `O(n)`.

Now about your questions. I don't know, how to implement this algorithm using the only stack effectively. The problem with stack is that we have access only to the top of it. But it is extremely easy to implement the algorithm with one array. Lets just do usual in-order traversal of a tree. For my example we will get: `arr = {2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 11}`. Then lets place `l` and `r` indexes to the closest to target values from both of the sides: `l = 3`, `r = 4` (`arr[l] = 5`, `arr[r] = 9`). What is left is just to always compare `arr[l]` and `arr[r]` and choose what to add to result (absolutely the same, as with two stacks). This algo also takes `O(n)` operations.

Their approach to the problem seems to me a bit too hard to understand in code, though it is rather elegant.

I'd like to introduce another approach to the problem with another running time. This algorithm will take `O(k*logn)` time, which is better for small `k` and worse for bigger ones than previous algorithm.

Lets also store in `TreeNode` class a pointer to parent node. Then we can find predecessor or successor of any node in tree easily in `O(logn)` time ([if you don't know how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182825/printing-successor-and-predecessor-in-a-bst)). So, lets firstly find in the tree predecessor and successor of the target (without doing any traversals!). Then do the same as with stacks: compare predecessor\successor, choose the closest one, and for the closest go to its predecessor\successor.

I hope, I answered your questions and you understood my explanations. If not, feel free to ask!

Comment: If you can't, or don't want to add a pointer to the parent, you can use two stacks.